# Linking to other packages in documentation in roxygen2 in R

Tags: r, documentation, roxygen2

I am wondering it there exists a method to `link` to function from other package when I'm trying to write a documentation for new package using `roxygen2`.
Something like `\link{pck=PACKAGE_NAME, fun=FUNCTION_NAME}`?

Comment: Try `\code{\link[MASS]{stats}}`, from [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html) (scroll way down).

Comment: Thanks. Mb you know where could I find a full list of roxygen2 documentation parameters like what's stand for `@param` or `@family` or so on? There are many that I couldn't find info about them anywhere. [For example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25293137/chapters-in-r-reference-manual-and-documentation-using-roxygen2):

Comment: roxygen2 now supports the more convenient `[MASS::stats()]` which evaluates to `\link[MASS]{stats}` when roxygen creates the .Rd files.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You have to type  `\link[pkg]{function}` e.g. `\link[stringi]{stri_c}`

Comment: so short answer but so valuable :)

Comment: note chapter "alternative documentation workflow" in [hadley's book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html). In order to see the links, you have to rebuild the package, not only re-document.

Answer (score 52):

`Roxygen2` now also supports documentation written in markdown.

The markdown syntax is for the link is `[foo::bar()]` which is translated to
`\code{\link[foo:bar]{foo::bar()}}` in the generated .Rd file. (See [Roxygen2 vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/rd-formatting.html#links).)

Note that you may need to specifically turn on Markdown support by writing `Roxygen: list(markdown = TRUE)` in your `DESCRIPTION` file, or by putting an `#' @md` comment if you want to enable markdown only for a specific man page. This is also explained at the very top of the linked vignette. (Thanks to @Tjebo for the comment)

Note that there are two colons in the markdown version whereas there is only one colon in the Rd version.

Comment: Wow, amazing!! Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the note about enabling markdown! I've seen recommendations elsewhere about using markdown style links and was infuriated when I couldn't get them to work :facepalm:

Comment: You can convert existing documentation using `roxygen2md::roxygen2md()`.

Answer (score 50):

There are two ways to achieve this, using:

### 1. `.Rd` syntax

From ["R packages" book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html#text-formatting):

> - `\code{\link{function}}` - function in this package.
> - `\code{\link[MASS]{abbey}}` - function in another package.
> - `\link[=dest]{name}` - link to dest, but show name.
> - `\code{\link[MASS:abbey]{name}}` - link to function in another package, but show name.
> - `\linkS4class{abc}` - link to an S4 class.

#### 2. markdown syntax

From [roxygen2 vignette](https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/articles/rd-formatting.html#links)

| roxygen2 comment | description | generated Rd code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `[func()]` | `func()` in this package | `\code{\link[=func]{func()}}` |
| `[pkg::func()]` | `func()` in the `pkg` | `\code{\link[pkg:func]{pkg::func()}}` |
| `[thing]` | topic in this package | `\link{thing}` |
| `[pkg::thing]` | topic in the `pkg` | `\link[pkg:thing]{pkg::thing}` |
| `` [`thing`] `` | topic in this package | `\code{\link{thing}}` |
| `` [`pkg::thing`] `` | topic in the `pkg` | `\code{\link[pkg:thing]{pkg::thing}}` |

*Remember to put `Roxygen: list(markdown = TRUE)` in the DESCRIPTION*
*Markdown shortcodes available from roxygen2>=6.0.0*

Comment: Is there any way to link to another (complete) package?

Comment: @bers see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70654391/r-package-documentation-link-to-a-whole-package-not-function

Comment: If you want another link text, use e.g. `[\`dgCMatrix\`][Matrix::dgCMatrix-class]`

Answer (score 13):

In addition to the answer by [potockan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3975896/potockan):
Some packages document several functions in a single help page. For example, the `trim` function from Bioconductor package [GenomicRanges](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicRanges.html) is documented in `intra-range-methods` (which is also the name of a help page from other packages such as [IRanges](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/IRanges.html)).

To link to the right page with `roxygen2` you can use:

```
\link[GenomicRanges:intra-range-methods]{trim}
```

or

```
\code{\link[GenomicRanges:intra-range-methods]{trim}}
```

to format the text correctly.

The help page will only show `trim` but will link to the right help page.

Comment: This was helpful when I wanted to link to the `dplyr` `dplyr_tidy_seelct` page. `\code{\link[dplyr::dplyr_tidy_select]{tidy-select}` resulted in a warning and broken link, but `\code{\link[dplyr:dplyr_tidy_select]{tidy-select}` worked.

Answer (score 0):

To link to a function, we slightly abuse markdown syntax by using `[function()]` or `[pkg::function()]`.

- Re-document your package by pressing Cmd/Ctrl + Shift + D.
- Build and install your package by clicking  in the build pane or by pressing Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + B. This installs it in your regular library, then restarts R and reloads your package.
- Preview documentation with ?