# R package documentation: link to a whole package, not function

Tags: r, documentation, roxygen2

I want to cite another package (the whole package, not just a function from it) in the documentation of some functions I'm developing. I am using Roxygen2 comments to document my package functions.

I cannot find a way to create a link to a whole third-party package using Roxygen2. To link to a package function, one would write `[pkg::fun()]` but I don't know how to create a link to the package itself.

Some packages expose a general man page, and it's possible to link to it via e.g. `[pkg::pkg]`.

But many packages don't have this and there's just a general package vignette with the list of functions and a link to the description:
[image]

Such page can be reached by clicking on a package name in the packages tab in RStudio.

How can I link to it from a function documentation made in Roxygen2 markdown.?

Comment: where in the documentation are you trying this? the description file? can you provide more detail in what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: No, in the documentation of one of my package functions. I want to specify in my function documentation that it relies on another package. I'm editing the question.

Comment: Does the other package have a package-level documentation page? Not all do. You can also just use a regular markdown or roxygen link to link to whatever you think is the best reference for the other package https://r-pkgs.org/man.html?q=link#links

Comment: They have, but I don't know how to reference it. How should I name it?

Comment: Without having a place I can test it out, `[pkg::pkg]` *might* work. If not, just use a full markdown link, e.g. `[roxygen2](https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/)`

Comment: The [pkg::pkg] solution works well for packages having general documentation page with its own man page, like `rentrez`. Other packages don't have this but still RStudio can show the general vignette if you click on the package name, so it should be linkable I guess. See for example `crrri`.

Comment: That's not a vignette though, that's just the list of exports. I'm not sure how that gets generated exactly, but it's automatic. Maybe just link to whatever functions / vignettes / etc seem most relevant, because if the package maintainer hasn't made package-level documentation, I don't know what else you could really reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to this ... My original answer seems to be partly wrong.

The manual *does* [mention](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/doc/manual/R-exts.html#User_002ddefined-macros) a possibility, which is (since R 3.2.0) the built-in macro `\packageIndices`.  If you want to link to the index of a package named **baz**, then you can ask `maintainer("baz")` to do the following.  Create a file `man/baz-index.Rd` containing

```latex
\name{baz-index}
\alias{baz-index}
\title{Index of Package \pkg{baz}}
\description{\packageIndices{baz}}
```

then build and install **baz** *twice* to bootstrap the index.  (The first stage generates the Rd objects that are used in the second stage to populate the index.)  After the second install, `help("baz-index", package = "baz")` and `` ?baz::`baz-index` `` will render the index.

The second tarball can be submitted to CRAN (or whatever repository), allowing other packages with at least `Enhances: baz` to link to the index in *their* help pages with `\link[baz]{baz-index}` or `\link[baz:baz-index]{<text>}`.

FWIW, I said that my original answer was *partly* wrong rather than *entirely* wrong because the built-in macro `\packageIndices` gives you an index without hyperlinks.  If you want hyperlinks, then you may need to hack, i.e., define your own macro calling a hacked version of `tools:::Rd_package_indices`.  Not worth the effort for one package, IMO, but could be an interesting proposal for **tools** ...

Answer (score 4):

You cannot link to the page that comes up when you click on the name of a package in RStudio's Packages pane. RStudio invisibly calls `help(package = "<name>")`, which renders the package's [index](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#The-INDEX-file).

From the `R-exts` [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Cross_002dreferences):

> The markup `\link{foo}` (usually in the combination `\code{\link{foo}}`) produces a hyperlink to the help for *foo*. Here *foo* is a *topic*, that is the argument of `\alias` markup in another `Rd` file (possibly in another package).

Hence `\link` and the equivalent Markdown markup supported by `roxygen2` can only link to topics. A package index is not a topic in this sense because there is no corresponding `Rd` file.

It might be best just to remind users that they can use `help` to access the index of the package to which you are referring.

Comment: that's a pity... Also because it appears in the Help tab of RStudio, so in theory it could be implemented someway