# R Roxygen link to help(pkg) in function details

Tags: r, roxygen2, roxygen

Is there a way for Roxygen documenting pkg how to include clickable link to the help page of r package in function details page? I see it is possible to include link to another functions `[pkg::fun()]` or any other link. I wish to click a link and jump to the help page `help(pkg)` I tried almost everything from here [Linking to other packages in documentation in roxygen2 in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25489042/linking-to-other-packages-in-documentation-in-roxygen2-in-r) but nothing did the job.

Comment: you can link to the [name](https://github.com/cran/ggplot2/blob/3995a1da465cb806b5c3c272210b582fd3974d25/R/utilities-tidy-eval.R#L42) or [alias](https://github.com/cran/ggplot2/blob/3995a1da465cb806b5c3c272210b582fd3974d25/R/utilities-tidy-eval.R#L44) of the help page. if you are writing the package, you can include a new `@aliases` tag to link to later

Comment: Aha, thank you very much. I got the trick now. I did not understand that the words after at `@aliases blah-blah` are linkable with `[blah-blah]`